# How to display each element in an array from Node in HTML?

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm using express to render a page in my node app and have sent an array to the client-side. I'm wondering how I can display each element as a paragraph in the HTML.

What I tried is below, but it does not work. When my `results` array is five elements long, I can see in Safari's Inspect Element that five `p` tags are created but they are empty.

Note that the `results` array was initiated and populated.

Node:

```
const app = express();

app.post('/home', (req, res) => {
    ...
    // results array gets populated here
    ...

    res.render('home', {results: results});
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="results">
    {{#each results}}
        <p>{{r}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like you're using handlebars as your view template engine? If so, you've not define "r" at all. Assuming "results" is an array of objects such as [{val: "hello"}] you can do {{val}} inside your p tag. If it's just a single value, not an object, then try using {{this}}.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn Thanks that worked! And yes, I was using handlebars. Sorry I'm new to Node... Thanks again for your quick reply :)

Comment: that's great news! I've added this as an answer for future searchers. Would you be able to mark it as correct?

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you're using handlebars as your view template engine? If so, you've not define `r` at all.

Assuming `results` is an array of objects such as `[{val: "hello"}]` you can do `{{val}}` inside your p tag. If it's just a single value, not an object, then try using `{{this}}`.

For a complete example:

```
<div class="results">
    {{#each results}}
        <p>{{this}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Or

```
<div class="results">
    {{#each results}}
        <p>{{val}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```